# Frustrated with simple awk command

Tags: awk, printf, newline

I am trying to list out the contents of a field 1 using a function:

```
help(){
     if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
     echo '######################################'
     echo ''
     echo 'Argument to run run name must be given: ./report.sh Name'
     echo 'Report names are:'
     ALLNAMES=$(cut -d '|' -f 1 $CONFIGFILE | awk '{printf $0"\n"}')
     echo $ALLNAMES
     echo '######################################'
     exit 0
     fi
}
```

The output I get is :

```
$ bin/report.sh
######################################

Argument to run run name must be given: ./report.sh Name
Report names are:
ItemA ItemB
######################################
```

Whereas I want:

```
$ bin/report.sh
######################################

Argument to run run name must be given: ./report.sh Name
Report names are:
ItemA
ItemB
######################################
```

If I run the cut command I get:

```
[david@kallibu]$ cut -d '|' -f 1 conf/report.conf
ItemA
ItemB
```

Whatdo I need to change to get my newline ?

Comment: try and put double quotes around the echo like `echo "$ALLNAMES"`. Also not that you could just use `awk '{print $0}'` no need for `printf` or the newline character

Comment: `cut` is already producing the output you want - what are you hoping the awk command will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be,

```
help(){
     if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
     echo '######################################'
     echo ''
     echo 'Argument to run run name must be given: ./report.sh Name'
     echo 'Report names are:'
     ALLNAMES=$(awk -F'|' '{print $1}' $CONFIGFILE)
     echo "$ALLNAMES"
     echo '######################################'
     exit 0
     fi
}
```

- You could try this `awk -F'|' '{print $1}' $CONFIGFILE` command to get the value of first column where `|` as delimiter.
- You need to put `ALLNAMES` inside double quotes. So that only, the `ALLNAMES` variable got expanded.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is:

```
echo $ALLNAMES
```

Should be solved with quotes:

```
echo "$ALLNAMES"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not goint to use the var **ALLNAMES** in other place, just:

```
help(){
     if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
     echo '######################################'
     echo ''
     echo 'Argument to run run name must be given: ./report.sh Name'
     echo 'Report names are:'
     cut -d '|' -f 1 conf/report.conf
     echo '######################################'
     exit 0
     fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tiago provided the answer to your specific problem, but overall your script should either be the shell script @klashxx posted or this awk script:

```
help(){
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    awk '
      BEGIN {
         FS = "|"
         print "######################################\n"
         print "Argument to run run name must be given: ./report.sh Name"
         print "Report names are:"
      }
      { print $1 }
      END {
         print "######################################"
      }
    ' "$CONFIGFILE"
    exit 0
  fi
}
```

or similar.